# Converting strings into an int array in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Lets say I have a string like this:

```
"1,2,5,8"
```

How can I make a function in VB to turn that into an array of ints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First split the string with the comma as separator and then convert each element in that resulting array into integer.

```
Dim ints = Array.ConvertAll("1,2,5,8".Split(","c), AddressOf Convert.ToInt32)
```